# finding min value with sorted list in c++

Tags: c++

I'm making a program with sorted list that has a  variety of functions I'm supposed to build in the header source file. So far I have everything working perfectly but when I ask for the min value the first time it gives me the second highest value, 1, instead of the lowest which is 0. It gives me the lowest number the second time I ask, but I assume it's because it's not reaching the end of the linked list, but I'm not sure what to change.

Here's the header

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H


class LinkedList
{
    private:

        struct Node
        {
            int data;
            Node *next;
        };

        int size;
        Node *head, *tail;

    public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();

        // misc
        void display();

        // sorting and searching
        // reverse --> sorting in descending
        int linearSearch(int key);
        void sort();
        void reverse();

        // various math
        int min();
        int max();
        int mean();

        // adding
        void append(int num);
        void insert(int num, int pos);

        // removing
        void pop();
        void remove(int pos);
};

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

source file

```
#include "linkedlist.h"

// GIVEN TO STUDENTS

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    if(head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *temp;

        while(head != nullptr)
        {
            temp = head->next;

            // deletes head
            delete head;

            // goes to next element
            head = temp;
        }
    }
}

void LinkedList::display()
{
    Node *temp = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << temp->data << "\t";

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void LinkedList::append(int num)
{
    // list is empty
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new Node;

        head->data = num;
        head->next = nullptr;

        // sets tail to head
        tail = head;
    }

    else
    {
        // creates new node
        Node *temp = new Node;

        // sets new node data
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = nullptr;

        // sets previous tail link to new node
        tail->next = temp;

        // sets this node to new tail
        tail = temp;
    }

    // increments size
    size++;
}

void LinkedList::pop()
{
    if(size > 1)
    {
        Node *temp = head;

        // loops to node before tail
        while(temp->next->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        // deletes tail
        delete tail;

        // sets new tail
        tail = temp;
        tail->next = nullptr;
    }

    // if there's only one item
    else if(size == 1)
    {
        Node *temp = tail;

        // head and tail are now null
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;

        // deletes node
        delete temp;
    }

    size--;
}

// END GIVEN TO STUDENTS
void LinkedList::insert(int num, int pos)
{
    if(pos ==0)
    {

        Node *temp=new Node;
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }

    if(pos>1)
    {
        Node *pre=new Node;
        Node *cur=new Node;
        Node *temp=new Node;
        cur=head;
        for(int i=1;i<pos+1;i++)
        {
          pre=cur;
          cur=cur->next;
        }
        temp->data=num;
        pre->next=temp;
        temp->next=cur;
    }



    size++;

}


int LinkedList::linearSearch(int key)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(temp->data == key)
        {
            return i;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return -1;
}

void LinkedList::reverse()
{
    Node* temp = head;

    // Traverse the List
    while (temp)
    {
        Node* min = temp;
        Node* r = temp->next;

        // Traverse the unsorted sublist
        while (r)
        {
            if (min->data < r->data)
                min = r;

            r = r->next;
        }

        // Swap Data
        int x = temp->data;
        temp->data = min->data;
        min->data = x;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::remove(int pos)
{
    Node *temp = head;

    if(pos ==0)
    {

        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }

    if(pos>1)
    {
        Node *current=new Node;
            Node *previous=new Node;
            current=head;
            for(int i=1;i<pos+1;i++)
            {
              previous=current;
              current=current->next;
            }
            previous->next=current->next;
        }





    size--;
}

void LinkedList::sort()
{
    Node* temp = head;

    // Traverse the List
    while (temp) {
        Node* min = temp;
        Node* r = temp->next;

        // Traverse the unsorted sublist
        while (r) {
            if (min->data > r->data)
                min = r;

            r = r->next;
        }

        // Swap Data
        int x = temp->data;
        temp->data = min->data;
        min->data = x;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int LinkedList::min()
{

    int min = INT_MAX;
       for(Node* temp = head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next)
       {
           if (head->data < min)
           {
               min = temp->data;

           }
        }

        return min;
}

int LinkedList::max()
{

    int max = INT_MIN;
        for (Node* temp = head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next)
        {
            if (temp->data > max)
            {
                max = temp->data;
            }
        }

        return max;

}

int LinkedList::mean()
{
    if (!head)
            return -1;

        int count = 0; // Initialize count
        int sum = 0;
        float avg = 0.0;

        struct Node* current = head; // Initialize current
        while (current != NULL) {
            count++;
            sum += current->data;
            current = current->next;
        }

        // calculate average
        avg = (double)sum / count;

        return avg;

}
```

and main

```
#include <iostream>

#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LinkedList nums;

    // adding through append
    nums.append(8);
    nums.append(6);
    nums.append(7);
    nums.append(8);
    nums.append(0);
    nums.append(9);

    // displays list
    cout << "List after append: " << endl;
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // adding through insert
    nums.insert(1, 0);
    nums.insert(5, 4);
    nums.insert(3, 7);

    // displays list
    cout << "List after inserting: " << endl;
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // testing searching
    cout << "Testing linear search:" << endl;

    int pres = nums.linearSearch(7);

    if(pres < 0)
    {
        cout << "7 is not present in the list." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "7 can be found at location " << pres << endl;
    }

    pres = nums.linearSearch(5);

    if(pres < 0)
    {
        cout << "5 is not present in the list." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "5 can be found at location " << pres << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    // does math
    cout << "Minimum, maximum, and average before removing any items: " << endl;
    cout << "Min: " << nums.min() << endl;
    cout << "Max: " << nums.max() << endl;
    cout << "Mean: " << nums.mean() << endl << endl;

    // displays items reversed
    cout << "Items reversed: " << endl;
    nums.reverse();
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // removing through pop
    nums.pop();
    nums.pop();

    // displays list
    cout << "List after popping: " << endl;
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // removing through remove
    nums.remove(0);
    nums.remove(2);
    nums.remove(4);

    // displays list
    cout << "List after removing: " << endl;
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // displays items sorted
    cout << "Items sorted: " << endl;
    nums.sort();
    nums.display();
    cout << endl;

    // does math
    cout << "Minimum, maximum, and average after removing items: " << endl;
    cout << "Min: " << nums.min() << endl;
    cout << "Max: " << nums.max() << endl;
    cout << "Mean: " << nums.mean() << endl << endl;

    // testing searching
    cout << "Testing linear search:" << endl;

    pres = nums.linearSearch(7);

    if(pres < 0)
    {
        cout << "7 is not present in the list." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "7 can be found at location " << pres << endl;
    }

    pres = nums.linearSearch(5);

    if(pres < 0)
    {
        cout << "5 is not present in the list." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "5 can be found at location " << pres << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first thing: `head->data < min` should probably be `temp->data < min`

Comment: Beat me by 41 sec `:)` Checking against `head->data` -- the scenery never changes...

Comment: I spent an hour looking and still didn't notice that. Thank you so much

Comment: `while (!code.works()) stateAtCode();` is not an efficient way to debug. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I assume this is a CS 010  (University Computer Spence introduction course). As @BessieTheCow noted, the most important thing is to learn to debug your programs. What is the environment you are using? Is it Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: I’m using QT creator

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo in your min function, it always compares head-data to the min instead of the temp node. Try this:

```
int LinkedList::min()
{

    int min = INT_MAX;

    for(Node* temp = head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next)
    {
        min = temp->data < min ? temp->data : min;
    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: That was it. I don't know why I didn't notice it

Comment: @x-reaper It's perfectly common not to notice obvious problems with code. One reason you should learn to use a debugger, which is very good at pointing out the obvious.